# Android WebView HTTP POST addressing form by name

Tags: android, webview, http-post

I'm currently using a static html to open a webpage using a POST and im trying to migrate it to my android app.

**Here's the working HTML code**

```
<body onload=\"document.forms['openCloud'].submit();\">
    <form name=\"openOwnCloud\" action=\"%1/index.php\" method=\"post\" >
        <div>
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"user\" value=\"%2\" >
            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"password\" value=\"%3\" >
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**And heres what I've tried so far to do the POST**, but i have no idea how do address the form name in that page programatically:

```
String url = SOMESERVER + mPath;
String postData = "username="+USERNAME+"&password="+PASSWORD;
webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
webView.loadData();
```

Can i get some help with that?